# Exclude attribute from filter if selected value = 'all'

Tags: jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute

The function below allows users to filter products by data-attributes, and accommodates filtering by multiple values simultaneously by creating an array of the values selected. I need to show all results matching any of the filters so I've structured the function with an `OR` statement. How can I modify the way it responds to `checked.filter(".all")` so that instead of showing all the products, it simply doesn't filter by that data-attribute?

I've posted a fiddle with a functional example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/hSwcr/1/ If 'Sleeveless' + 'Red' is checked is shows all items that are either 'Sleeveless' OR 'Red'. If the user then checks 'All Colors' is checked I want to ignore the color filter *(`data-color="All"`)* and only apply the style filter *(`data-style="Sleeveless"`)* - so that it shows 2 items instead of all the items.

```
    var selected = { color: [], style: [] };   
    $('.filterOptions').on("change", ":checkbox", function (e) {
        var type = $(e.delegateTarget).data("type");
        var $this = $(this);
        var attrValue = $this.data(type);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected[type].splice(selected[type].indexOf(attrValue),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected[type].push(attrValue);
        }            
        var checked = $(":checked", ".filterOptions");            
        // show all of the available options if...
        if (checked.length == 0 || checked.filter(".all").length > 0) {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } 
        else {
            $("#content").find("*").hide();
            for (var key in selected) {
                $.each(selected[key], function(index,item) {
                    $('#content').find('[data-' + key + ' *="' + item + '"]').show();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are "Colors" and "Styles" completely separate? Meaning if Blue and Crew Neck is selected is it supposed to show Blue Crew Necks only or is it supposed to just filter by whatever you -just- clicked

Comment: You could just ignore the "all" checkbox if anything else is checked, but from a UI perspective, that might be confusing. I would recommend making it so that if any of the individual attributes are checked, it automatically unchecks "all". And similarly if "all" is checked, it automatically unchecks all the individual attributes.

Comment: @BenLee I was doing it this way because I think it's probably easier for the user if it doesn't changed what's been checked. That way if they uncheck the 'all' value they don't have to check all the values again

Comment: @DaiYoukai - For this page I need it to show all items matching any values that are checked, so it should show any items that are either Blue or Crewneck

Comment: @DaiYoukai - For this page I need it to show all items matching any values that are checked, so it should show any items that are either Blue or Crewneck. I added a bit more detail to the example above, which should hopefully make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the `if` logic:

```
        if (checked.length == 0 // ...no boxes are checked
            || // ...or...
            checked.filter(".all").length > 0)
```

to something like:

```
        if (checked.not(".all").length == 0)
```

This allows individual filters to override the "all" logic.

Comment: That solves part of the problem :-) But I actually need it to exclude the entire filter because if I just modify that line it is still filtering by the colors which were already checked (as I explained to @BenLee, I think it's easier for the users if I don't uncheck those values when they check 'all').

Comment: I realized that I might not have been as clear as I'd intended in the example I gave, so I added a bit more detail which should hopefully clarify things